# How to teleport Minecart with chests above a players head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been having trouble making menu GUIs in 1.16. My best idea so far was to create a command making it so when ever there is a nether star in my inventory it teleports a minecart with a chest in it to me. But the problem is it teleports it to my feet, and not my head. Here are the commands I used:

`/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:nether_star",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Menu"}'}}}]}]` **(to find a nether star in my inventory)**

`/teleport @e[type=minecraft:chest_minecart,y=3] @p` **(to teleport the minecart)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use ~ ~2 ~ instead of @p! If you teleport an entity to another entity the entity you teleport will always get teleported to the feat! But if you only replace @p with ~ ~2~ the minecart will be teleported to the command block! To fix that you must do it like this:  /execute as @p at @s run tp @e[type=minecraft:chest_minecart,y=3] ~ ~2 ~

I hope that solve your problem!

Do you know you dont need to type /teleport! /tp will also work :)

Comment: Thank You so much! I've been trying to find the answer to this for like 3 days! (and btw ik you can use /tp XD I don't even know why I did /teleport)